# How to adapt the size of a JPanel with the size of the window

Tags: java, window, jpanel, calculator

I'm new to java and as a project, we have to code a calculator in 
reverse polish notation.

We have got a problem in the display of the window because the size the JPanel Bas that includes the 2 JPanels Chiffres and Operateurs doesn't change when we extend the window

```
JFrame Fenetre = new JFrame ("Calculatrice");
        JButton Bouton0 = new JButton("0");
        JButton Bouton1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton Bouton2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton Bouton3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton Bouton4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton Bouton5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton Bouton6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton Bouton7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton Bouton8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton Bouton9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton BoutonVirgule = new JButton(",");
        JButton BoutonSigne = new JButton("+/-");
        JButton BoutonAddition = new JButton("+");
        JButton BoutonSoustraction = new JButton("-");
        JButton BoutonMultiplication = new JButton("x");
        JButton BoutonDivision = new JButton("/");
        JButton BoutonPush = new JButton("PUSH");
        JButton BoutonSwap = new JButton("<->");

        JPanel Chiffres = new JPanel();
        Chiffres.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
        Chiffres.add(Bouton7);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton8);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton9);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton4);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton5);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton6);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton1);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton2);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton3);
        Chiffres.add(BoutonVirgule);
        Chiffres.add(Bouton0);
        Chiffres.add(BoutonSigne);

        JPanel Cases = new JPanel();
        Cases.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
        Cases.add(Ligne1);
        Cases.add(Ligne2);
        Cases.add(Ligne3);
        Cases.add(Ligne4);
        Cases.add(Ligne5);

        JPanel Operateurs = new JPanel();
        Operateurs.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        Operateurs.add(BoutonAddition);
        Operateurs.add(BoutonSoustraction);
        Operateurs.add(BoutonMultiplication);
        Operateurs.add(BoutonDivision);
        Operateurs.add(BoutonSwap);
        Operateurs.add(BoutonPush);

        JPanel Bas = new JPanel();
        Bas.add(Chiffres);
        Bas.add(Operateurs);

        Fenetre.getContentPane().add(Bas,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Fenetre.getContentPane().add(Cases,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Fenetre.pack();
        Fenetre.setVisible(true);
        Fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

In fact, I want a mix between both cases in the sense that the positioning of Operateurs isn't conserved in the 2nd picture ( Operateurs Panel should be smaller than Chiffres Panel, as on picture 1 )

Photo without the GridLayout added to Bas

[image]

Photo with the GridLayout added to Bas

[image]

Black=Cases Green=Bas Pink=Chiffres Cyan=Operateurs

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: See if adding `Bas` (should be bas btw) to `BorderLayout.CENTER` is what you want. If not, apply a different Layoutmanager to contentpane.

Comment: I tried to add Bas to BorderLayout.Center but it just change the position of the JPanel, the size is still blocked.

Comment: Try to add to Bas panel also a gridlayout => e.g. GridLayout(0,2);

Comment: It would be best if you use names in English. Also stick to Java naming conventions. Both make your code more readable here. 
For better help post [MCVE].

Comment: I assume you want something like https://imgur.com/a/Gsxoi

Comment: Yes exactly this kind of positionning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace these:

```
Fenetre.getContentPane().add(Bas,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
Fenetre.getContentPane().add(Cases,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

with:

```
Fenetre.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
Fenetre.add(Bas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
Fenetre.add(Cases, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what behavior you want. Try this :

```
    JPanel bas = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));//assign a layout manager 
    bas.add(chiffres);
    bas.add(operateurs);
    fenetre.getContentPane().add(bas,BorderLayout.SOUTH); //or CENTER
```

Comment: In fact, I want a mix between both cases in the sense that the positioning of Operateurs isn't conserved in the 2nd picture ( Operateurs Panel should be smaller than Chiffres Panel, as on picture 1 ) 

[Photo without the GridLayout added to Bas][1]

[Photo with the GridLayout added to Bas][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhRLx.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf49x.png

Black=Cases Green=Bas Pink=Chiffres Cyan=Operateurs